# DOM setInterval will load on document.ready but not on a function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, setinterval

This is my first question, so please have patience.

I'm doing an exercise for my course. I have to call a Scheduler that instantiates a setInterval object. If i instantiate from jQuery all runs fine, but if i call from a function, the interval wont start. I can't understand the reason behind the different behavior. Any ideas why?

I have a node.js/express server running "on server side" but it's irrelevant for this context.

Here is my html:

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var  ResetableScheduler = function(callback, miliseconds, data){
        var handler;
        this.start = function (){
            handler = setInterval(function(){callback(data + "\t(" + miliseconds + ")")}, miliseconds);
        }

        this.reset = function(newdata){
            clearInterval(handler);
            handler = setInterval(function(){callback(newdata + "\t(" + miliseconds + ")")}, miliseconds);
        }

        this.stop = function(){
            clearInterval(handler);
        }
    }

            // runs fine
    //$(function(){
    //  var rs = new ResetableScheduler(doTranslate_pt_en_2, 200, "Hello");      
        //rs.start(); 
        //setTimeout(function() { rs.reset("JavaScript"); }, 2500); 
        //setTimeout(function() { rs.stop(); }, 6000); 
    //});

    function doTranslate_pt_en_2(text){
        console.log("text = " + text);
    }

            // prints begin and then nothing...
    function begin(text)
    {
        console.log("begin");
        var rs = new ResetableScheduler(doTranslate_pt_en_2, 200, "Hello");      
        rs.start();
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form method="post" action="/api/translate/pt/en">
            <input type="textbox" id="originaltext" name="originaltext">
            <input type="submit" id="translate-btn" onclick="begin(originaltext)" label="traduzir">
        </form>

        <input type="textbox" id="translatedtext" placeholder="<%= result %>">
    </div>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: When the user clicks the "submit" button, the `<form>` is submitted and the page reloaded with the response from the server. A page reload resets everything.

Comment: so this behavior is because of the form submission, if i just had a button with no form the function would act has expected right?

Comment: Yes - you'll also have to fix the "onclick" handler. If you want to pass a string, it must be quoted: `onclick="begin('message')"`

Answer (score 1):

Attach your instantiation code to the form's `submit` event:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    var rs = new ResetableScheduler(doTranslate_pt_en_2, 200, "Hello");      
        rs.start();
});
```

In this case, you can then remove the `onclick` code you've attached on the submit button.

Comment: Thanks, i tried your code and i can see your point but it doesn't work, the behavior is the same